# slideToggle with a sticky nav

Tags: jquery, fixed, slidetoggle, scrolltop, sticky

I have a promo area above my utility and navigation bars that can be shown and hidden using slideToggle, by clicking a link in the utility bar.

When the user scrolls down so that the top of the utility bar reaches the top of the window, I'd like the promo area to toggle to `display: none` and the entire header (promo, utility, and main navigation) to have `position: fixed`.

[Here is an example](http://stanislav.it/tutorials/sticky-navigation/) of the sticky nav effect I'm trying to achieve, but is this possible in conjunction with an element that uses slide toggle?

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Sukiyaki/rCS85/1/)
*Note: Small grey box represents logo in header, and large grey box represents page content.*

Answer (score -1):

Do you mean something like this?

If so, I will continue and implement handling a user scrolling all the way back up

```
var $utility = $('#utility'),
$promo = $('#promo'),
$nav = $('header');

$(window).on('scroll', function (ev) {
    var $windowTop = $(this).scrollTop(),
        $utilityTop = $utility.offset().top;

    if ($utilityTop <= $windowTop) {
        $nav.css('position', 'fixed');
        $promo.css('display', 'none');
    }
});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/rCS85/2/)